# RN Javascript - modifying entries in object list

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, object, logic

Got a logic issue that's been driving me crazy all day; hope you guys can help!

So I'm using the google maps api to return a list of events from a calendar, then I'm filtering those events for specific ones that the user belongs to (email is in attendees); now I'm trying to extract the event attendees, check for the other users email, run a query against that to return their name and picture, then append that object with their name and picture to the original event, then return the whole list again with the updated entries.

Here's the event I get from the server:

```
{ ...
  id: 'ID',
  status: 'confirmed',
  description: 'Keyword' 
  start: [Object],
  end: [Object],
  attendees: [Array],
  reminders: [Object]
  ...
}
```

I pull the email of the attendee who's not the user and run a query on my local database to get their name and picture, then I want to add then so the event shows as such;

```
{ ...
  id: 'ID',
  status: 'confirmed',
  description: 'Keyword' 
  start: [Object],
  end: [Object],
  attendees: [Array],
  reminders: [Object]
  ...
  opponent: {name: 'Name', picture: 'Picture_URL'}
}
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
const events = results.data.items.filter(event => {
    return (
      event.description &&
      event.description.includes('Keyword') &&
      event.attendees.some(attendee => {
        return attendee.email === currentUser.email;
      })
    );
  });
```

`Events come back fine from here, filtered with the events that include the user in attendees. I can't seem to get the next bit to work where I would modify the {event} object and add the {opponent} to it.`

```
  const opponent = events.map(event => {
    return event.attendees.filter(async attendee => {
      if (attendee.email !== currentUser.email) {
        return await prisma.query
          .user({ where: { email: attendee.email } })
          .then(user => {
            return {
              name: user.name,
              picture: user.picture,
            };
          })
          .catch(err => {
            return;
          });
      }
    });
  });
```

P.S: the prisma.query.user returns a Promise.

Would greatly appreciate any direction or help as to what I'm missing!

Thanks guys! :)

Comment: `const opponent = events.map(()=>{})` are you getting correct values for opponent here?

Comment: It actually returns an array with all the event attendees, which is not what I want..